# Как правильно проверять wait_timeout?

Tags: java, mysql

Есть база. У базы переменная 'wait_timeout' установлена на 300 секунд(для debug мода на 60). Хочу сделать проверку, которая определяла бы срок 'wait_timeout' истёк или нет(короче говоря нужно ли переподключаться к базе). Проблема в том, что я не знаю с какого момента точно начинается отсчёт 'wait_timeout'. 
При создании соединения

```
private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    //long m = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(start);
    if ((connection == null) || (connection.isClosed())) {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(plugin.getSettings().getUrl(), plugin.getSettings().getLogin(), plugin.getSettings().getPassword());
    }
    return connection; (Java)
}
```

или при первом запросе в базу(хотя соединение не является ли первым запросом?).

Comment: отсчет идет от времени последнего запроса в БД. если вы чуть чаще чем раз в 300 секунд выполняете какой нибудь запрос (любой, хоть `select 1`) соединение никогда не закроется

Comment: И я предпочитаю, если скрипт долго спит, при пробуждении выполнять этот самый пресловутый `select 1` если вернул ошибку - то переподключаюсь

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Лишний раз ловить ошибку try catch блоком не хочется)